# Два вопроса о выпадающем списке

Tags: javascript, css

Есть выпадающий список, реализованный примерно следующим образом:

```
    <ul>
<li>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <p>Блок 1</p>
   <span>
    <b>Тут много текста</b>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ENTER HERE">
   </span>
</li>
<li> 
   <div class="block"></div>
   <p>Блок 2</p>
    <span>
     <b>Тут много текста</b>
     <input type="text" placeholder="ENTER HERE">
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

В списке есть какой-то текст, и форма.

JS :

```
$(function(){
  $('ul li').click(function(){
  $('span', this).toggle();
});
});
```

Сейчас проблема в том, если нажать на форму, то список тут же закроется, как этого избежать?

Также с помощью css я добавил треугольник, который при клике должен поворачиваться на 180 градусов, как лучше всего это реализовать?

Вот пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8c7effx/1/)

Comment: там инпут есть внутри

Comment: Я специально выложил пример на jsfiddle, чтобы не было вопросов, при нажатии на input список закрывается, вопрос, как это избежать? Какая страница перезагружается?

Comment: а чего ж не закрываться, если вы на ли давите. сделайте тогл при нажатии на какую-то часть

Comment: как вариант можно добавить обработчик клика по инпуту, в котором вызвать [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=text]').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();    
});
```

При нажатии на input список не закрывается

Добавляем класс который поворачивает стрелку

```
$('.block', this).toggleClass('selected');
.selected
{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 20px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример рабочего кода: https://jsfiddle.net/z8c7effx/16/.

```
$(function(){
  $('ul li').click(function(){
    if(!$('input').is(':focus')){
      $('span', this).toggle();
      $('.block', this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
  })
})
```